# How to immediately execute AsyncHTTPClient() without server (using interactive interpreter)

Tags: python, asynchronous, tornado, asynchttpclient, python-interactive

I typed [`AsyncHTTPClient` sample code](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/httpclient.html#tornado.httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient) from tornado's website in an interactive python interpreter but the asynchronous HTTP request is never executed.

```
def handle_request(response):
    if response.error:
        print "Error:", response.error
    else:
        print response.body

http_client = AsyncHTTPClient()
http_client.fetch("http://www.google.com/", handle_request)

# handle_request function is never executed (nothing is printed)
```

Can I use `AsyncHTTPClient` not as part of a web server processing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, but you should start an [IOLoop](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/ioloop.html#tornado.ioloop.IOLoop), example from [docs](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/httpclient.html#tornado.httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient):

```
from tornado import ioloop
from tornado.httpclient import AsyncHTTPClient


def handle_request(response):
    if response.error:
        print "Error:", response.error
    else:
        print response.body
    ioloop.IOLoop.instance().stop()

http_client = AsyncHTTPClient()
http_client.fetch("http://www.google.com/", handle_request)
ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```